# NGINX not caching images or sending added headers

Tags: nginx, configuration, cache

add_header directive and the proxy directive seems to be ignored. I am using nginx as a cdn to serve images and I would like it to cache the images. The below is my sites available for the cdn. The images are served fine but I don't see the X-Cache-Status in the headers nor does it seem to be populating the cache path with any content.

What am I missing?

nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

```
proxy_cache_path /var/www/html/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cdn:100m max_size=25g inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name applebeescdn;

  # Proxy Cache
  proxy_cache cdn;
  proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri $cookie_user";
  proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
  proxy_cache_valid 200 302 120m;
  proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
  proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
  proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
  proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
  proxy_buffering on;

  location / {
    expires $expires;
    root /var/www/html/;
    add_header 'X-Cache-Status' "$upstream_cache_status" always;
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you read this guide? Could be anything, including inappropriate caching headers on the images from upstream. You'll need to provide much more detail if you want help, including curl with headers - edit your question don't reply as a comment. It's more normal to define your cache within a location, but is valid within a server. https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how to use `proxy_cache`.  You have to have a `proxy_pass` if you are using `proxy_cache` (i.e., a separate origin server for which this nginx instance is acting as a reverse proxy).  You can read more about how to set up an origin server [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/).